# failover management in ubuntu16.04 server

Tags: failover, failovercluster

I have two ubuntu 16.04 servers in a vpn. 
first server is an application server which contains a php,mysql and a windows virtual machine. 
i need to implement the second server as a failover for my first server.For files sharing rsync & mysql master-slave for replication of Dbs. Then how can i implement a complete failover mechanism in it(if first server fail the control changes to backup server fully). i found some tuitorial for implementing apache failover. But i need the full system failover including Vm. is there any tool ubuntu for doing it..?.

Answer (score 2):

In order to create a 2-node "failover" cluster you have to possess some shared storage (or emulate one) and install additional packages for clustering like pacemaker, cman, corosync, drbd and ocfs2. I assume there's no SAN available, so DRBD takes care of disk synchronization between the nodes.

Here is a great step-by-step guide that might help you to start with:
http://linux.opm.si/programska-oprema/linux-gruca-cluster.